# LinqToSql PredicateBuilder How to retrieve the last inserted value

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, predicatebuilder

I have two tables

```
Table Products
-ID
-Name
-Description
...
```

And

```
Table Price
-ProductID
-Price
-DateAdded
```

How do I create a Predicate which we will return the list of products whose price is greater than 10

I tried the following query

```
Dim predInner As Expression (Of System.Func (Of tblProduct, Boolean)) = PredicateBuilder.True (Of tblProduct) ()
                     predInner = predInner.And (Function (a As tblProduct) a.tblPrice.Select (Function (c) c.Price). First ()> 10)
                     pred= pred.And (predInner)
Me.Grid.DataSource = vQuery.Where (pre)
```

but not always return the last inserted value. Is it possible for this part

```
a.tblPrice.Select (Function (c) c.Price). First ()
```

in some way to sort by column DateAdded

Comment: Can you not do a.tblPrice.OrderByDescending(....).Select(...).First()?

Comment: yes, thanks, this is solution :)

Comment: @ChrisDunaway you should post that as an answer to get the bounty...